# Replace all instances of string in table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT  'weeshadmin'
FROM  `wp_postmeta` 
REPLACE ('weeshadmin','a0h80gxqegrd')
```

This doesn't work either:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, 'weeshadmin', 'a0h80gxqegrd')
```

How can I replace all instances of the first string with the second? I can verify that that both strings are unique. It's a small database.

Comment: The `wp_postmeta` table stores keys and values.  Is `weeshadmin` a key or a value (and the same question for `a0h80gxqegrd`) ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an update?

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    SET <col> = 'a0h80gxqegrd'
    WHERE <col> = 'weeshadmin';
```

I'm not sure what column you want to update, but that should be clear from the structure of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following update query:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = 'a0h80gxqegrd'
WHERE meta_value = 'weeshadmin';
```

This assumes that you only want to blanket update all values, but not keys, in your `wp_postmeta` table.

Comment: I get the following error: ``#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'a0h80gxqegrd' WHERE meta_value = 'weeshadm' at line 1``

Comment: Did you copy my query _exactly_ as it appears above?  You seem to have run `PDATE wp_postmeta ...` and obviously that won't work.

Comment: @santafebound - Try `UPDATE` as mentioned in the answer instead of `PDATE`.

Comment: Whoops. Interesting. ``0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0023 sec)``

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 'weeshadmin'` ... do you get any records back?

Comment: ... No. ``MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0007 sec)``. But I swear that I should...

Comment: Edit your question, and show us sample data, including records which you want to update.  Then, show a second table with the expected output.  We can't read your mind as to what data you actually have here.